# Best Way to Index Multiple Effective Date Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index, sql-server-2016, index-tuning

I've got a table that is primarily to represent relationships between entities (i.e. mostly composed of foreign keys). These relationships change over time, and so the table has a StartDate and an EndDate column. I now need to add another dimension of start and end dates, meaning that the relationship can be viewed with two different date "lenses" (queried with two dates, @Date1 and @Date2), so the schema will look something like this:

```
MyJoinTable:

| Id | Entity1Id | Entity2Id | StartDate1 |  EndDate1  | StartDate2 |  EndDate2  |
|----|-----------|-----------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|  1 | A         | B         | 1753-01-01 | 2018-09-01 | 1753-01-01 | 2025-01-01 |
|  2 | A         | B         | 2018-09-01 | 2018-10-01 | 1753-01-01 | 2018-11-01 |
|  3 | A         | C         | 2018-09-01 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-11-01 | 2025-01-01 |
|  4 | A         | B         | 2018-10-01 | 2025-01-01 | 1753-01-01 | 2018-11-01 |
|  5 | A         | D         | 2018-10-01 | 2025-10-01 | 2018-11-01 | 2025-01-01 |
```

The queries will mostly be joins to this table, for example:

```
SELECT e1.Field, e2.Field
FROM Entity1 e1
INNER JOIN MyJoinTable jt ON jt.Entity1Id = e1.Id
    AND StartDate1 <= @Date1 AND EndDate1 > @Date1
    AND StartDate2 <= @Date2 and EndDate2 > @Date2
INNER JOIN Entity2 e2 ON e2.Id = jt.Entity2Id
```

My questions are:

1. What's the best way to index this join table?

   - Index on Entity1Id
   - Index on Entity2Id
   - Composite Index on all four date columns? (StartDate1, EndDate1, StartDate2, EndDate2)
2. What's the best way to constrain the DB so that I only get one relationship row returned for any @Date1, @Date2 combination?
3. Do you have any recommendations on a better data model?

Comment: When they add a third and fourth lens this is going to get really ugly, really fast.

Comment: Since the query is trying to relate points - the `(@Date1, @Date2)` "point" - with rectangles -  the `(StartDate1, EndDate1) - (StartDate2,EndDate2)` "rectangle" - in a 2D (time) space, you need an index for spatial queries, like the ones mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-spatial-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Problem is these specialized indexes exist only for spatial (geometry) datatypes and not for datetime-spatial types (there is not even a type like that in SQL Server).

Comment: To achieve 2 you could only have StartDate EndDate with a 1 day gap.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ That's a neat insight. Do you know of anyone who has mapped non-spatial data into a spatial plane, stored it in SQL Server geometry datatypes, and used a spatial index to query it? I'm not considering it for this particular problem, but that would be a fun blog post/case study to read.

Comment: Spatial works with numbers.  Dates can be turned into numbers.  QED.  OK, the numbers are stored as DOUBLEs, but that does not matter.  And don't get into spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Seafish I have added two more solutions to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introduction

I do not have the time for extensive testing, but can suggest from where
to start.

If you rewrite the query in a more symmetrical manner, to
emphasise that both entities are joined to a two-dimensional
cross-section of `MyJoinTable`:

```
SELECT E1.Field, E2.Field
FROM MyJoinTable JT
JOIN Entity1 E1 ON E1.Id = JT.Entity1Id
JOIN Entity2 E2 ON E2.Id = JT.Entity2Id
WHERE
    StartDate1 <= @date1 AND EndDate1 > @date1 AND
    StartDate2 <= @date2 AND EndDate2 > @date2
```

you will see that one reasonably efficient way of executing it is first
to extract that cross-section and then to join the entities to it.
The following equivalent query will serve for illustration purposes
(but do not use it!):

```
-- A sample to demostrate the desired order or execution:
SELECT E1.Field, E2.Field
FROM
-- 1. Calculate the cross-section:
(   SELECT JT.Entity1Id, JT.Entity2Id
    FROM MyJoinTable JT
    WHERE 
        StartDate1 <= @date1 AND EndDate1 > @date1 AND
        StartDate2 <= @date2 AND EndDate2 > @date2
) SECT
-- 2. Join the entity tables:
JOIN Entity1 E1 ON E1.Id = SECT.Entity1Id
JOIN Entity2 E2 ON E2.Id = SECT.Entity2Id
```

It is the more important since you say that there is only

> one relationship row returned for any @Date1, @Date2 combination.

For this reason, joining the entities in before `MyJoinTable` is reduced
to the required cross-section by `@date1` and `@date2` is inefficient as
it is likely to have many records for each entity so that the result
will have too many rows. The entites are best joined at the end, using
their natural key field, `Id`, which I assume is the clustered index.
The solutions below, therefore, propose different ways of calculating
this cross-section, corresponding to the `SECT` subquery of the example
above—

### Soution I: The easiest

Let us try to add useful indices to the original query.  Since *MSSQL*'s
composite indices are hierarchical, they are useless in optimising
interval comparisons, so the best we can do with the given structure is
to index one of the date fields, yet make sure to cover all the other
fields required form the table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SD1 ON MyJoinTable ( StartDate1 )
INCLUDE (Entity1Id, Entity2Id, StartDate2, EndDate1, EndDate2 )
```

The query then will be executed in the following order:

1. Using the index `SD1`, perform an index seek on `MyJoinTable`
   to find records by `StartDate1`, and filter them by `StartDate2`,
   `EndDate1`, and `EndDate2` in the
   [residual predicate](https://www.sqlshack.com/the-impact-of-residual-predicates-in-a-sql-server-index-seek-operation/)
2. Join the entity tables using their natural key `Id`.

This method is not very efficient because only one of the four date
predicates is fully optimised by an index, resudual predicates being
boring data grinders.

### Solution II: Set intersection

Another symmetrical way to obtain the two-dimensional `JOIN`
cross-section goes through `INTERSECT`ing the results of the four date
predicates:

```
SELECT Entity1Id, Entity2Id
FROM
(   SELECT Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date1 >= StartDate1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date2 >= StartDate2
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date1 <  EndDate1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date2 <  EndDate2 )
SECT
```

With the suitable indices,

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SD1 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate1)
    INCLUDE (Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SD2 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate2)
    INCLUDE (Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ED1 ON MyJoinTable (EndDate1  )
    INCLUDE (Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ED2 ON MyJoinTable (EndDate2  )
    INCLUDE (Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id)
```

the plan for this query includes only clean *index seek* (wihout residual
predicates) and *hash match* operations.

Observe that the entity keys in query and indices present a
fourfold redundancy, which may be removed—at the expense of a more
complicated execution plan—by joining the entities in separately:

```
SELECT JT.Entity1Id, JT.Entity2Id
FROM
(   SELECT Id FROM MyJoinTable WHERE @date1 >= StartDate1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id FROM MyJoinTable WHERE @date2 >= StartDate2
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id FROM MyJoinTable WHERE @date1 <  EndDate1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id FROM MyJoinTable WHERE @date2 <  EndDate2 )
SECT
JOIN MyJoinTable JT ON JT.Id = SECT.Id
```

with these indices:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SD1 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate1) INCLUDE (Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SD2 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate2) INCLUDE (Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ED1 ON MyJoinTable (EndDate1  ) INCLUDE (Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ED2 ON MyJoinTable (EndDate2  ) INCLUDE (Id)
```

But since in either case each of four date predicates, bounding the date
on one end only, does not reduce the amount of data sufficiently, *hash
matches* may have to
[spill](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/spills-week-hash-match-aggravation/)
data into `tempdb`. If they do, this method is not fit for your
environment.

### Solution III: A compromise

Now we can merge solutions I & II in order to come up with a plan that
does not require so much RAM and at the same time is reasonably fast:

```
SELECT Entity1Id, Entity2Id FROM
(   SELECT Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date1 >= StartDate1 AND @date1 < EndDate1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id, Entity1Id, Entity2Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date2 >= StartDate2 AND @date2 < EndDate2  )
SECT
```

Now the date constraints are more efficient in discaring data
because they bound the date on both ends. With the indices below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SE1 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate1)
    INCLUDE (EndDate1, Entity1Id, Entity2Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SE2 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate2)
    INCLUDE (EndDate2, Entity1Id, Entity2Id)
```

each constraint uses an index seek with a residual predicate, which is
better than the single index seek in solution I and takes less RAM
than solution II. The plan shows three opportunities of parallisation:
one for each date constraint, and one for the `INTERSECT` operation.

A non-redundant version of this approach would be:

```
SELECT JT.Entity1Id, JT.Entity2Id FROM
(   SELECT Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date1 >= StartDate1 AND @date1 < EndDate1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Id FROM MyJoinTable
    WHERE @date2 >= StartDate2 AND @date2 < EndDate2  )
SECT
JOIN MyJoinTable JT ON JT.Id = SECT.Id
```

with indices

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SE1 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate1)
    INCLUDE (EndDate1, Id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SE2 ON MyJoinTable (StartDate2)
    INCLUDE (EndDate2, Id)
```

Although it should work better with your data, where the `SECT` subquery
returns at most one row, in my crude tests with randomly generated data
it has been less efficient because the server used a hash match instead
of a nested loop join with that single row. Do try it on your side.

### Solution IV: Optimised structure

It is possible to optimise your query at the expense of introducing a
more complicated structure that requires additional maintenance and
slows down the modification of data in `MyJoinTable`. If you are willing
pay the price, store the date ranges as sets of days:

```
CREATE TABLE MyJoinTable
(   Id         INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Entity1Id  INT,
    Entity2Id  INT,
    Range1     INT, -- reference to Ranges.Id 
    Range2     INT  -- reference to Ranges.Id
)

CREATE TABLE Ranges
(   Id    INT,
    Date  Date
)
```

and query the relation thus:

```
SELECT E1.Field, E2.Field
FROM MyJoinTable JT
JOIN Entity1 E1  ON E1.Id = JT.Entity1Id
JOIN Entity2 E2  ON E2.Id = JT.Entity2Id
JOIN Ranges  R1  ON R1.Id = JT.Range1
JOIN Ranges  R2  ON R2.Id = JT.Range2
WHERE
    R1.Date = @date1 AND
    R2.Date = @date2
```

You will need some testing in order to determine optimal indices, but I
think the following should work:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX RD ON Ranges      ( Date   ) INCLUDE ( id )
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX RR ON MyJoinTable ( Range1, Range2 )
-- optionally: INCLUDE (Entity1Id, Entity2Id)
```

Index `RD` will make sure the ranges are quickly found corresponding to
the specified dates, and index `RR` will help to find the record
matching these ranges. But then you shall have to devise a means of
filling the `Ranges` table and keeping it in sync with `MyJoinTable`,
because doing so by hand is out of the question.

Comment: A thorough and well-considered answer. I appreciate the optimized structure example because I can see how that would more easily scale if another date dimension were added.

Comment: @Seafish you are welcome. I liked the question because it shows how an apparently primitive problem may be hard to solve well.